# Copy directories containing Java files while excluding certain directories in Dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, build, dockerfile, containers

I am working on a Dockerfile where I need to copy directories containing Java files to a specific location within the container's file system. However, I want to exclude certain directories from the copy process.

Here is the relevant part of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim-buster

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Run a shell command to find directories containing Java files and copy them to /app
RUN find . -type f -name '*.java' -not -path './docs/*' -exec sh -c 'mkdir -p "/app/$(dirname "{}")" && cp "{}" "/app/$(dirname "{}")"' \;
```

When I build the Docker image using this Dockerfile, the copy process does not work as expected. The directories containing Java files are not copied to the desired location.

Here is an example scenario to clarify the requirement:
Let's say my current working directory on the host machine is as follows:

```
./
├── folder1
│   ├── file1.txt
│   └── file2.doc
├── folder2
│   ├── file3.java
│   └── file4.py
└── folder3
    ├── file5.xml
    └── file6.java
```

In this case, I am interested in cloning the following directories and their contents to the Docker container:

```
/app
├── folder2
│   ├── file3.java
│   └── file4.py
└── folder3
    ├── file5.xml
    └── file6.java
```

I suspect there might be an issue with the shell command used in the `RUN` instruction . Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this problem and suggest a possible solution? Thank you!

Comment: You should use `COPY` or `ADD` instead of `RUN`. The `RUN` command is only executed inside Docker Container and does not know your machine. Use `.dockerignore` to be able to exclude files/folders when copying